# How use different menu item in different page in react ionic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, menu, ionic-react

I am new in react ionic and want to show different menu item in different page. I have one menu component and included it in App.tsx. But same menu item is showing in each page. 
Any help be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

`const appPage: AppPage[] = [
  {
    title: 'Home',
    url: '/home',
    icon: home
  },
  {
    title: 'Register',
    url: '/home/register',
    icon: home
  },
  {
    title: 'Login',
    url: '/home/login',
    icon: home
  }
];`

```
    <IonRouterOutlet id="main">
      <Route path="/home" component={Home} exact={true} />
      <Route path="/home/register" component={Register} exact={true} />
      <Route path="/home/login" component={Login} exact={true} />
      <Route path="/home/dashboard" component={dashboard} exact={true} />
      <Route path="/home/forgot_password" component={Forgot} exact={true} />
    </IonRouterOutlet>
  </IonSplitPane>`
```

This is menu
`interface MenuProps extends RouteComponentProps {
  appPages: AppPage[];
}`
const Menu: React.FunctionComponent = ({appPages}) => (`<IonContent className="menu_list">
      <IonList className="ion-padding-menubar">
        {appPages.map((appPage, index) => {
            return (
              <IonMenuToggle  key={index} autoHide={true}>
                <IonItem routerLink={appPage.url} routerDirection="none">
                  <IonLabel color="light">{appPage.title}</IonLabel>
                </IonItem>
              </IonMenuToggle>
            );
          })}
      </IonList>
    </IonContent>`

Comment: can you provide some code , with minimum reproducable issue so we can check

Comment: sure, I have updated the post